# In Intellij idea Community Edition version 2016.1.1 can i use database then how

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij idea Community Edition version 2016.1.1 there database missing i am searching in View>>Tool Windows>> here can't find database how can i use database in this Edition.

Answer (score 3):

Database tool windows function is supported in ***Intellij IDEA ultimate edition*** only.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html

If you want to use database in intellij community edition then use "database navigator plugin" from below link.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator

Answer (score 0):

Community Edition doesn't contain the database tools.
See here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows